# How to use partial to access application's scripts?

Tags: php, zend-framework, partial

I know to access scripts from another module, you just pass the module name as second argument, but I can't find how to access scripts from application/views folder.

I tried as follow, but didn't work :

```
echo $this->partial('myscript.phtml', 'application', $this);
echo $this->partial('myscript.phtml', '', $this);
```

But none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $this->partial('myscript.phtml', 'default', $this);
```

The main application is commonly reffered to as the 'default' module.